# Max size Limit in avro

Tags: avro

How can the maximum size/length restriction be put for a data type in Avro Schema generation. Eg: In a schema, I want to specify a field which takes string of max len 25.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a "fixed" avro type and specify the length.

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Fixed

**Fixed**

Fixed uses the type name "fixed" and supports two required attributes:

- *name*: a string naming this fixed (**required**).

  - and *namespace*, a string that qualifies the name;
- *size*: an integer, specifying the number of bytes per value (**required**).
- *aliases*: a JSON array of strings, providing alternate names for this enum. (optional)
- For example, 16-byte quantity may be declared with:

`{"type": "fixed", "size": 16, "name": "md5"}`

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the size of the attribute must be exactly as it was specified? But what if I need to specify the maximum size? Like from 0 to 16 characters?

Comment: @ZZa I guess the idea behind it is that a fixed field does not require length encoded into a message body, as it is always known from  a writer schema definition. While any variable-size field like array or string needs a length in the message body. As avro is for message encoding, it makes no sense to make it as a part of standard for a message validation rules like min/max length, non-empty/lowercase/phonenumbers/etc.